# Approach to testing a JSR 168 portlet

Tags: java, testing, portlet

For a simple project when I don't need an MVC framework like Spring - how should I test my JSR 168 portlet? The business layer is easy enough with jUnit but how do I do functional/integration testing?

I found portletUnit but that seems like a dead project?

Comment: FWIW: I am trying to get it going with PortletUnit but it's not documented at all and I'm not sure where to begin. If you had any insights after this posting let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always go with something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to test the user interface. I can't say anything about PortletUnit since I never tried it.

Comment: Thanks for your input Dirk. I thought about that to but it seems a little "clunky" when I have start up my portlet container when running tests. Also I can't deal with mocking? I have to deploy a mocked version if I don't want to hit external API's for example.